User can't access a database because he belongs to multiple AD groups
We have an SQL Server 2016 that has 20 different databases on it that are used by different applications and different teams in the company. There are groups of users in Active Directory that combine employees that work on certain projects. The problem is that an employee can be part of several teams at the same time. The same person can belong to several different AD groups.
One user complained that he could not access a certain database. When he was trying to refresh the Power BI report that queries that database he was getting an error message "We couldn't authenticate with the credentials provided".
Here is a simplified picture.
A server has two databases: DB1 and DB2.
There are two AD groups App_Excel_Reporter and DB2_User and two corresponding logins in the SQL Server:
CREATE LOGIN [LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]

CREATE LOGIN [Domain\DB2_User] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[master]

Not sure if this is important, but this server is a legacy server that was part of another company that the main company bough. So, this SQL Server computer is in domain LegacyDomain.
Two AD groups LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter and Domain\DB2_User have their own sets of users, but one user Jack.Universal belongs to both AD groups.
Users that are part of App_Excel_Reporter should have access to DB1. Users that are part of DB2_User should have access to DB2.
In DB1 there is a user mapped to the corresponding login:
USE [DB1]
GO
CREATE USER [LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter] FOR LOGIN [LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

In DB2 there is a user mapped to the corresponding login:
USE [DB2]
GO
CREATE USER [Domain\DB2_User] FOR LOGIN [Domain\DB2_User] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA=[dbo]
GO

When a user Jack.Universal tries to refresh the Power BI he is logged into Windows on his laptop as Domain\Jack.Universal and I see these messages in SQL Server log with the same timestamp:
Login succeeded for user 'Domain\Jack.Universal'. Connection made using Windows authentication, [CLIENT: <ip address>]
Error: 18456, Severity: 14, State: 38.
Login failed for user 'Domain\Jack.Universal'. Reason: Failed to open the explicitly specified database 'DB2'. [CLIENT: <ip address>]

When I run
xp_logininfo 'Domain\Jack.Universal', @option = 'all'

it shows
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
|     account name      | type | privilege |   mapped login name   |         permission path         |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter |
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | Domain\DB2_User                 |
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | Domain\DB3_User                 |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+

(yes, there is more than two databases and this user belongs to three AD groups)
If I run
xp_logininfo 'Domain\Jack.Universal'

without option "all", then only the first row is returned:
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
|     account name      | type | privilege |   mapped login name   |         permission path         |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+

So, it seems that when a Windows user Domain\Jack.Universal logs into the SQL Server, the SQL Server picks login LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter to let the user in, but when it tries to access a database DB2 this attempt fails because login LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter is mapped only to the user in DB1.
"the explicitly specified database" must be due to Power BI's connection string which explicitly specifies DB2.
How do we configure this so, that a user who belongs to both AD groups would have access to both databases? Users who belong only to one AD group should have access only to the corresponding database.
I am not a domain admin, but I can ask them whatever is needed. The company doesn't have a DBA, I'm just a programmer who knows a thing or two about SQL Server.

I dug a bit deeper.
When I run
EXEC xp_logininfo 'Domain\DB2_User', @option = 'members'

I get a list of users in that group:
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+
|     account name      | type | privilege |   mapped login name   | permission path |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+
| Domain\user1          | user | user      | Domain\user1          | Domain\DB2_User |
| Domain\user2          | user | user      | Domain\user2          | Domain\DB2_User |
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | Domain\DB2_User |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+-----------------+

And the users are in Domain as expected.
When I run
EXEC xp_logininfo 'LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter', @option = 'members'

I get this:
+-----------------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
|        account name         | type | privilege |      mapped login name      |         permission path         |
+-----------------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| LegacyDomain\user3          | user | user      | LegacyDomain\user3          | LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter |
| LegacyDomain\user4          | user | user      | LegacyDomain\user4          | LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter |
| LegacyDomain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | LegacyDomain\Jack.Universal | LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter |
+-----------------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+

Here permission path is in LegacyDomain and account name is also in LegacyDomain, but above in the results of xp_logininfo 'Domain\Jack.Universal' the account name is in Domain, but permission path is in LegacyDomain.
Once again:
EXEC xp_logininfo 'Domain\Jack.Universal', @option = 'all'

+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
|     account name      | type | privilege |   mapped login name   |         permission path         |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter |
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | Domain\DB2_User                 |
| Domain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | Domain\Jack.Universal | Domain\DB3_User                 |
+-----------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------+---------------------------------+

EXEC xp_logininfo 'LegacyDomain\Jack.Universal', @option = 'all'

+-----------------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
|        account name         | type | privilege |      mapped login name      |         permission path         |
+-----------------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+
| LegacyDomain\Jack.Universal | user | user      | LegacyDomain\Jack.Universal | LegacyDomain\App_Excel_Reporter |
+-----------------------------+------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------------+

There must be some magic in Active Directory that maps users from legacy domain into the main domain.

This is the end user, most likely he doesn't have SSMS on his laptop, but I'll check tomorrow. I will also make sure that he reboots his laptop. Is there any other lightweight tool / command line to try connecting to the database apart from SSMS? I don't want to make the user install SSMS just for troubleshooting.

"Is there any other lightweight tool...": I often use .UDL files for this purpose. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/connect/test-oledb-connectivity-use-udl-file

@DougDeden, this is brilliant! I did not know about UDL files. Excellent tool. Unfortunately, the user is away sick today. Most likely I could resume troubleshooting only next week.

If you add or remove an AD user to an AD group, and you want to enforce those changes immediately without the user logging off, then the user needs to execute the following command in a cmd or Powershell window
klist purge

If it's a machine which you have added/removed then you need
klist -li 0x3e7 purge

What this does is it clears the Kerberos ticket cache, so the next time a Kerberos ticket is needed then the Domain Controller is contacted for a new TGT ticket, and the new ticket contains the updated list of groups. Otherwise the cache would hold the ticket until expiry (usually 10 hours) or logoff.
To confirm the changes, execute
whoami /groups


For what I know, if you tried using Universal Groups in Active Directory to access your SQL Servers, you notice that the users who are members of these groups can’t access the SQL Server Instance. The reason for this has more to do with active directory than with SQL Server.
Normal groups in Active Directory are cached so authentication requests can return groups that the user is a member of as part of the Windows Token. Universal groups, however, aren’t included in the Windows Token as the Universal groups that the user might be a member of might not be in the same domain that the request is handled by.
Because the Universal Groups aren’t in the authentication token when the SQL Server goes to see if the user has access, the token says that the user doesn’t.  The fix for this is quite easy, use a different Windows Domain Group type than Universal Groups.
I don't know whether enabling universal group caching can fix the issue:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/plan/planning-global-catalog-server-placement#enabling-universal-group-membership-caching

Thank you for the answer, but it turned out to be much simpler. A day has passed after a user was added to a new AD group and they rebooted their computer as well. So, now the problem disappeared by itself. My guess is that originally something was not completely synchronized between AD controller, user computer and the SQL Server.

@VladimirBaranov adding users to groups in AD generally requires a log off and log on of the user for the new groups to be added to the token for the user. SQL is reading the token that Windows passes it when using Windows Auth.

Thanks @SeanGallardym I did not know it. Apparently, our domain admin didn't know that as well. Besides, by asking this question I also learned about UDL files.
